# Using Log4J 1.*, how can I write two packages to two separate files?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, filtering, slf4j

I have the following two packages:

com.mycorp.project.first
com.mycorp.project.second

I'd like to configure Log4J (SLF4J) to write the logs from one package to one file, and from the other package to a second file. I do not want them to be mixed in together.

To be clear, this is one project/one process running.

I've tried filtering and with loggers but they seem to be ignored by log4j. Both files are always identical.

Edit: Thank you for the answers so far, this is what I've got and it's not working. Both output files are identical.

```
<configuration debug="true">
<contextName>dev</contextName>

<appender name="FIRST_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>A:/dev/LogTesting/logs/first.log</file>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>A:/dev/LogTesting/logs/first.%d{yyyyMMdd}%d{_HHmmss,aux}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="SECOND_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>A:/dev/LogTesting/logs/second.log</file>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>A:/dev/LogTesting/logs/second.%d{yyyyMMdd}%d{_HHmmss,aux}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <Pattern>%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %property{HOSTNAME} [%thread] %level %logger{36} %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- =============================================================== -->
<logger name="com.test.apples" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="FIRST_FILE"  />
</logger>

<logger name="com.test.oranges" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="SECOND_FILE"  />
</logger>
<!-- =============================================================== -->

<category name="com.test.apples" additivity="false">
    <priority value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FIRST_FILE"/>
</category>

<category name="com.test.oranges" additivity="false">
    <priority value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="SECOND_FILE"/>
</category>

<!-- =============================================================== -->

<!-- default -->
<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="FIRST_FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="SECOND_FILE" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this is the example of properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CONSOLE
# Each package has different appender name     
log4j.logger.com.mycorp.project.first=DEBUG, FIRST
log4j.logger.com.mycorp.project.second=DEBUG, SECOND

log4j.appender.FIRST=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FIRST.File=./first.log
log4j.appender.FIRST.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.SECOND=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SECOND.File=./second.log
log4j.appender.SECOND.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

or this for XML (only highlight important part):

```xml
<!-- FIRST appender definition -->
<appender name="FIRST" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    ...
</appender> 

<!-- SECOND appender definition -->
<appender name="SECOND" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    ...
</appender>

<!-- logger package com.mycorp.project.first -->
<logger name="com.mycorp.project.first">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="FIRST"/>
</logger>

<!-- logger for package com.mycorp.project.second -->
<logger name="com.mycorp.project.second">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="SECOND"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I have an xml configuration file. What's the equivalent of this in xml?       log4j.logger.com.mycorp.project.first=DEBUG, FIRST

Comment: I have two questions on this:

1. If the difference between appenders is just the filename, is there a way to define the common properties once (XML) to avoid redundancy?

2. Is it possible to map one logger to multiple packages?

Answer (score 2):

Create two appenders `LOG1` and `LOG2`, one for each log file. After that define two categories(one for each package) with reference to these appenders int the log4j config file.

```
<category name="com.mycorp.project.first" additivity="true">
    <priority value="TRACE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="LOG1"/>
</category>
```

Appender2

```
<category name="com.mycorp.project.second" additivity="true">
    <priority value="TRACE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="LOG2"/>
</category>
```

Answer (score 1):

put dynamiclly file path .in log4j.properties

```
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${file.name}
```

And in  java set file path `System.setProperty("file.name", FILEPATH);`

Answer (score 0):

you just specify 2 appenders, but give same output log file name for both.

```
#same appender for both packages
log4j.logger.package1=INFO,MyCommonLogger    
log4j.logger.package2=INFO,MyCommonLogger

log4j.appender.MyCommonLogger=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MyCommonLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MyCommonLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%t %d{MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss} %x %-5p %c %M - %m%n

#single log file for logs from both packages
log4j.appender.MyCommonLogger.File=/somewhereonserver/log/mysinglelogfile.log
```