# How to exclude a package from a log4j appender

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have configuration file (log4j.properties), see the packages below and and question at the end.

```
  com.bitguiders.package1
  com.bitguiders.package2
  com.bitguiders.package3
  com.bitguiders.package4
  com.bitguiders.package5
  com.bitguiders.package6
  com.bitguiders.package7
```

I want to log everything except this package

```
 com.bitguiders.package2
```

How can i do that ? (Assume i have 50 packages and still i wanted to exclude one or two pacakges)

Comment: Don't add an Appender for that package. Then nothing will be logged.

Answer (score 15):

You can set the log [`Level`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html) to [`OFF`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html#OFF) for some packages:

```
# set the log level 
log4j.logger.com.bitguiders=INFO
log4j.logger.com.bitguiders.package2=OFF
log4j.logger.com.bitguiders.packageX=OFF
```

Edit:

You can log to a file using a [`FileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html), like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/somepath/somefile.log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
```

Edit:

In order to send log from different packages to different files:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, FILEA, FILEB
log4j.logger.com.bitguiders.package1=INFO, FILEA
log4j.logger.com.bitguiders.package2=INFO, FILEA
log4j.logger.com.bitguiders.package3=INFO, FILEB
```

This was answered here: [Using Log4J 1.*, how can I write two packages to two separate files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564159/using-log4j-how-can-i-write-two-packages-to-two-separate-files)

Comment: Thanks, if i want them to log in file then still it ll work for me ?

Comment: Yes, it should work. You can also configure different levels per appender

Comment: Thanks, let me try. Appreciated

Comment: Thank you for updating your solution. I appreciate your help. but in my case i want to log in separate file lets say

com.bitguiders.package (all sub packages excluding few) should log in File1
com.bitguiders.package1.thirdSubPackage  should log in File 2

Comment: Maybe in this case you can define the appenders by package: `log4j.logger.com.bitguiders.package2=DEBUG, FILE2`