# Is there a way to clean up stack traces for logging purposes?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j

I'm developing an application on a Java EE server and the logs get written to file and console.

As of the application server's implementation, the calls to the java methods in the beans are managed by the Java EE magic. This causes the stack traces to contain a lot of interceptor calls and I have to scroll a lot in the log to trace back the root of the problem in the logs.

Is there a way to remove elements from certain packages (org.*) from the stack trace when logging them with Log4J so I don't have to scroll so much? I want to be able to enable that only in the configuration on my developer machine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064418/how-to-exclude-a-package-from-a-log4j-appender

Comment: @Joshgun that's about enabling/disabling logging, not about filtering stacktraces. AFAIK there's no common way of making the stacktrace prettier, and it's better to get all the information in it anyway. Maybe you should use something else to look at the logs than just a normal editor?

Comment: If you use PatternLayout, it looks like you [can configure the exception](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) (see the "ex|exception|throwable" pattern) to suppress stack frames with certain packages using `{filters(packages)}`—at least for Log4j-2. Not sure if you can use wild cards, however.