# Separate logging files for different applications

Tags: logging, log4j, wildfly

I have the following problem:

There are many applications deployed to my wildfly 8 server that ( now ) all log into the same log file. Since the maintenance effort gets huge with the amount of applications deployed, i want to split the log files for every application. How could this be achieved?

Comment: If the naming of the package structure of each application is different, you can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564159/using-log4j-how-can-i-write-two-packages-to-two-separate-files) as basis.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage the logging configurations and allow for runtime changes you could use [logging profiles](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-LoggingProfiles).

The other option would be to use a logging configuration [for each deployment](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-PerdeploymentLogging).

One thing to note is all server modules, e.g. Hibernate, RESTEasy, will always be logged with the main logging configuration.